Science fiction story from around 2010 whose title was something like "Angels at (something)"
I'm looking to identify a science fiction story I read in a magazine ages ago. I think around 2010, though it may have been a few years either side of that. It might have been in Analog, Asimov's, or another big-name magazine, though I can't find it in any of their searchable archives.
The title was something like "Angels at (something)," where the something is a number, like the way fighter pilots would call out contacts. It's about mysterious alien craft attacking human aircraft, but only above certain altitudes, and the human fighter pilots who have to confront them.
(Searches so far show a story called "Rendezvous at Angels Thirty" by Tom Ligon in Analog May 2009 — I don't think it's that though based on the description.)

My brain immediately kicks up the name "Angels at Apogee," but I think it was earlier.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

Rendezvous at Angels Thirty - "This is an interesting tale of simulated flight, a simulation pilot reliving historical combat engagements. I enjoyed the characterization and the time period references a lot. The ‘mystery’ that the main character, the pilot, is seeking to solve draws the plot along nicely and the technology used is described in as much detail as required to make believable. And I’m always a fan of air combat and those scenes were well done." Doesn't match your story in the slightest.

Not Angels at the Border (by Ian Rennie; https://magazine.metaphorosis.com/story/2017/angels-at-the-border-ian-rennie/

There are only three stories on ISFDB with the title "Angels at" and it doesn't appear to be any of them; https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Angels+at&type=Fiction+Titles. There's only one "At Angel"; https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?173413 and it's not that one either.

It's not At Angels Sixteen by Lawrence Santoro. https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1105163. That's the story of a man who gets shot down in WW2

@DavidW - It's not Angel at Apogee; Daughter of Two Worlds: To her fellow pilots Gaelian is an Angel, the best of their elite fighting force. To the powerful ruling Board of Dinoreos, she is the Eldest of the Eldest of her household, scheming and plotting to claim her rightful place, while she strives on the primitive world of Cahaute. But Gaelian is haunted by memories. Even in space she feels the Power Clans of Cahaute with her—though to surrender to the magic of her childhood would mean abandoning the honors and privileges she has worked so hard for on Dinoreos.

It's not Angel at the Gate; https://www.williamflew.com/omni33a.html or Angel at my Shoulder (""Brent, a child kidnapper, gets terrified by a little blond girl.")
